# puppetserver package not present in xenial and bionic repo

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, puppet, puppetmaster

Just found that puppetserver opensource package is not present in xenial and bionic repo.Instead puppetmaster package is present.Eventhough the puppet version is 5.x is there any reason why they have not included puppetsever.

All puppet documentation says puppetmaster is deprecated and replaced by puppetserver.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask the '*why is it missing*' question. Ask Ubuntu is just a community of (mostly) average Ubuntu users, *not* people who make decisions. You may have to ask people from Canonical Ltd. (the Ubuntu company).

Answer (score 0):

The Puppet daemon is `puppetmaster.service`
`puppetmaster` can be found in the `universe` repositories for Xenial and Bionic


If needed, see [How to add Universe repo from CLI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding_the_Universe_and_Multiverse_Repositories)

Then install the [`puppet-master` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=puppet-master)

```
sudo apt install puppet-master
```